# MS Graph API GET Group members only get users

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Currently i have a request for getting the members of a group. But can someone help my composing a request that only show objects of type microsoft.graph.user so i don't have groups in my group members request?
The current request:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GROUPID/members?$select=id,displayName,givenName,mail,surname,userPrincipalName

Answer (score 2):

The standard way to achieve your requirement would be to apply type case such as https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GROUPID/members**/microsoft.graph.user**?$select=id,displayName,givenName,mail,surname,userPrincipalName. There is currently a bug that fails the above query. Please use query like https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/GROUPID/members/microsoft.graph.user in the meantime as a workaround. Notice the changes in version from v1.0 to beta and the lack of $select. We will soon fix the bug to get the former query working.

Comment: Hello. Can you tell us when this will be fixed? Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is till happening.